# Rsync fails when copying to a mounted NFS share in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I run the command to copy data between one server and another. The /remote dir is mounted via /etc/fstab as an NFS share.

```
root@server2:/usr/local/bin# rsync --bwlimit=10000 -axWSr --progress --timeout=600 --partial --numeric-ids --log-file=/var/log/sync-$date.out /media/data/share/ /remote/server2/share 2> /var/log/sync-$date.err
```

And get the output:

```
sending incremental file list
    Global/
    Global/Briefing.odp
          1,594,680 100%   15.68MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, ir-chk=1227/1233)
```

I have left this for a week and still nothing more happens. The cursor is just blinking in the terminal. I have a normal 1GB network.

Comment: Can you still access `/remote` via other means? This lookslike a stale NFS mount.

Comment: yes cd and ls to it works fine from server2

Comment: Do you have ssh login between the two servers? If so you will get a far more efficient transfer with `rsync` by using that instead of NFS. Update your question and I'll be able to post you an answer